# fMRI datasets for emotion states

Tags: neuroscience, fmri

Would there be any open fMRI datasets available that specifically analyse a subjects emotional state? The objective is to apply deep learning methods to categorise subjects emotional state based on the fMRI images. Raw or processed data would be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where can i find preprocessed fmri data set for alzheimer's disease](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/16824/where-can-i-find-preprocessed-fmri-data-set-for-alzheimers-disease)